# Referencing a Bachelor's Thesis

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

LaTeX only offers `@mastersthesis` or `@phdthesis`, but no bachelor's thesis.

I tried to keep the entry as `@misc`, but the university name doesn't appear.

So I just used `@mastersthesis` and typed

```
type = "{B.S. Thesis}"
```

Is there another way of doing this -- or could I create a new `@bachelorthesis` entry type in the `.bst` file?

Comment: This should be possible with `biblatex` (somewhat easily). I suspect if it is at all possible with standard `.bst` files, it's probably not worth the hassle.

Comment: @moewe - It's not much hassle either to modify a copy of a bibliography style such as `plainnat`. :-)

Comment: @Mico I did not think it would be that easy. Being a `biblatex` fan I really underestimated `natbib` and friends.

Comment: @moewe - Many forms of modifying a `.bst` file are indeed quite tedious. Fortunately, adding a new entry type is not -- especially if one can use an existing entry type as a template!

Comment: There are many types of thesis and `@mastersthesis` provides the field `type` just for this purpose. I wouldn't bother creating a new entry type just for a couple of citations. Before editing (a copy) of an existing `.bst` style, consider that for a submission you would have to use `@mastersthesis` anyway and you can't share your `.bib` file with your coworkers unless they have the new `.bst` file: using personally modified styles limits document portability.

Comment: I had a similar problem and solved with this technique: https://hci.rwth-aachen.de/materials/bib/?id=kluth2011a

Comment: [This discussion at Citavi Forums](https://support.citavi.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=5454) states it would be possible to overwrite the subtitle directly, by setting the `subtitle` field of the quote. I didn't try it out myself, though. However, there does seem to be an optional `subtitle` field in the `@mastersthesis` entry type. Also, I'm not sure if that would result in what the OP wants, as the question implies that the OP would like the Bachelor's thesis to explicitly appear in the reference typename. However, it's not entirely clear to me what purpose this has - in the resulting docu

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way to do so is to use `@masterthesis` and then setting the `type` to *Bachelor's Thesis* which will get printed instead of the default *Master's Thesis*. That is:

```latex
@mastersthesis{Oezoguz2012,
    ...
    type={Bachelor's Thesis}
    ...
}
```

---

## Old Answer

The new way to reference a Bachelor's Thesis is to use `@thesis`, which also replaces `@phdthesis` and `@mastersthesis` (both can still be used).

```
@thesis{Oezoguz2012,
...
type={Bachelor's Thesis}
...
```

In `type` you can write whatever you want. But `mathesis` and `phdthesis` are predefined for Master's Thesis and PhD Thesis respectively.

Comment: Can you provide a source for the `@thesis` type?

Comment: This did not work for me, maybe because of an old LaTeX installation at my institution. The type and school were not shown. However, when I changed `@thesis` to `@phdthesis` it worked as expected.

Comment: That doesn't work with BibTeX.

Comment: Similar to m00am: "Warning--entry type for "joachim2018methodology" isn't style-file defined"

Answer (score 15):

It's not LaTeX *per se* but the bibliography style you use that determines, among many things, which types of bibliographic entries are recognized. If you're using a bibliography style such as `plainnat`, it's not much work at all to create a new entry type named, say, `@bachelorsthesis`. The following instructions should work not just for `plainnat` but for many other bibliography styles too, as long as they feature a function called `mastersthesis`.

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call it, say, `myplainnat.bst`. (Don't edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `myplainnat.bst` in your favorite text editor and locate the function called `mastersthesis`. (It starts on line 910 in my copy of the .bst file.)
- Copy the code of the entire function (ca. 16 lines) and paste the copy below the existing function.

  - Change the new function's name from  `mastersthesis` to `bachelorsthesis`.
  - Change the string `"Master's thesis"` to `"Bachelor's thesis"`.
- Save the new `.bst` file either in the same directory as your main `.tex` file or somewhere in your TeX distribution's search path. If you choose the latter method, you will probably need to update the filename database in a way that's appropriate for your TeX distribution.
- Start using the new bibliography style by invoking it via `\bibliographystyle{myplainnat)`, rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully update all references and citation call-outs, and start creating and citing those entries of type `@bachelorsthesis`. :-)

Happy (Bib)TeXing!

Answer (score 2):

Specifying the type of thesis within @mastersthesis

```
@mastersthesis{McGregor:2032,
  ...
  type = "Bachelor's thesis"
```

works for me when using \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}.